# Fetch records by interval

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table that stores the following data:

```
id_event INT(10)
start_date DATE()
end_date DATE()
```

My goal is to show all id_events that are included between the interval betweeb to dates: `$start` and `$sto`

I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE $start >= start_date AND $end <= end_date;
```

But the problem is that it might be some events that start before the input `$start`, and ends after `$end` and does not show.

I'm pretty sure that it might be quite easy, but i'm stucked with this for last 2 days

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely if an event starts before, and ends after, it shouldn't be displayed? If your logic is that an event might have started before `$start` and ended after `$end`, you're including every record older than the current one? Is your aim to match all records that occupy that timescale?

Comment: so do you want events that started after `$start` and ended before `$end` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date >= '$start' AND end_date <= '$end';`

Comment: Sorry, I've appended the graph in the wrong message. Apologize me, but I can't remove :(

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to make sure `$start` and `$end` are in the right format.  It should be: `'YYYY-mm-dd'`, for example: `'2013-07-22'`.

Second, your logic is flawed.  `$start >= start_date` is the same as `start_date <= $start`.  Which means anything on or *before* the date entered as `$start`.

Finally, you need to quote your values in your query, your dates should be strings.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date >= '$start' AND end_date <= '$end';
```

Comment: Out of interest, any particular reason for the order of the operands there? Is there a significant performance enhancement?

Comment: @BenM: That's how he had it.  I think there may be an issue with his logic too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE $start <= end_date and $end >= start_date;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends what is in $start and $end. 
I assume this comes from PHP, right?

I think you need to convert whatever is in that PHP variable first to SQL DATE type, using STR_TO_DATE function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Then, having used the correct format, you run something similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE STR_TO_DATE('$start','%d-%m-%Y') >= start_date AND STR_TO_DATE('$end','%d-%m-%Y')  <= end_date;
```